# Concatenation of instance objects, should order matter?

Tags: python-2.7

I came across this curiosity after creating a simple class and instantiating it,

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,inp):
            self.id = inp
    def get_id(self):
            return self.id
    def __add__(self,other):
            return other + self.id
```

And the instantiation,

```
me = A('Matt')
```

Now when I try to use the overloaded method `__add__` it works as expected,

```
me + ' test concatenation'
```

but when I do it the other way around, `'test concatenation ' + me`, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects
```

Why does the order of the arguments matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the '+' notation is implicitly calling first.__add__(second).

Under the covers, when you have an expression like "hello" + " world", you are actually executing this: string.__add__(string). Hence, the __add__ method is that of the first argument, which is why the order matters.